# I need javascript css builder?

Tags: asp.net, javascript

I'm creating Content management system in asp.net. But I need open source cascading stylesheet builder like visual studio style builder. 
Can anyone know existing css builder?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found this nice nline utility with a bunch of options to build your style.

[QrONE CSS Designer](http://www.qrone.org/cssdesigner.html)

and a downloadable one

[Rapid CSS Editor - Cascading style sheet editor](http://www.blumentals.net/rapidcss/)

and

[Style Master](http://www.westciv.com/style_master/)

Style Master is the leading cross platform CSS development tool. Much more than just a text editor, Style Master supports your workflow - including

```
* creating style sheets based on your HTML
* live CSS editing of PHP, ASP.NET, Ruby and other dynamically generated sites
* editing CSS via ftp
```

and much much more.

Answer (score 0):

This is unrelated to JavaScript but a tool for building CSS is [TopStyle](http://www.topstyle4.com/).